# Distance range IR sensor

Tags: sensor, infrared

What should be the distance between the object and the sensor (TCRT5000L), for sensor to be able to detect it? I foun in datasheet operating distance is 0.2 to 0.15mm, but it seems little to me.

Comment: Figure 9 in the datasheet shows you the signal vs. distance for a reflective target. You want to be within that range or closer if your target is not very reflective.

Comment: With software augmentation, I've seen these give detectable signals off white ceiling tiles (about 2M away). The difference between photodetector output with LED switched on/off was added together from multiple pulses. Much better range than a simple DC method.

Comment: Please link to the datasheet in future questions. Make it easy for your readers.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Read the datasheet again.  0.2 to 15 mm, not 0.2 to 0.15 mm.